# Problem with subplot code and integer error

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Hi I am trying to run the following code:

```
plt.figure()
subplotsize = np.ceil(np.sqrt(len(localpeaks)))

imRawMovie = io.imread('DNAPAINT_substack.tiff')
singleFrameRawMovie = imRawMovie[30,:,:]


for l in range(0, len(localpeaks)):
  #Extract the ROI - we know it is centered around the localpeaks[l,:] position, with radius ROIradius
  ROI = singleFrameRawMovie[localpeaks[l,0]-ROIradius:localpeaks[l,0]+ROIradius+1,
                    localpeaks[l,1]-ROIradius:localpeaks[l,1]+ROIradius+1]
  #Show the ROIs in a subplot image
  plt.subplot(subplotsize,subplotsize,l+1)
  plt.imshow(ROI,cmap='gray')
```

I am getting an error regarding integer. Can anyone please help me with this issue? I am aslo attaching a screenshot of the error[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w8gF.jpg)

I have tried finding the error but I failed

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

`np.ceil()` returns a `float`, not `int`. Use `math.ceil()` instead.

```
import math

subplotsize = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(localpeaks)))
```